# Connection Issue on paho mqtt library

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

I use [paho.mqtt.android](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android) for routing messages realtime  but when i close the app completely and restart the app in connecting to broker state this exception occurres :

D/BrokerAndroidClient: exp:Exception: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent** { cmp=com.messenger.myapplication/org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{b6f36c3 u0a460 CEM  idle change:cached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}

Should i use my mqtt android client in a service?
Or should i use JobScheduler ?

Device Api = 28
minsdk  = 26

Comment: Are you stopping the service when you close your app? It seems like the service is still running after you close the app, and then when you open it again and try to start the service again, it is already running, and that causes that IllegalStateException. Can you post some code in order to get a clear view?

Comment: About the questions about what you should use, it depends on your app architectural design, the way you want it to work and perform, and even the kind of activity your app will be working with.